# Issue with $auth being null

Tags: vue.js, axios, auth0

I am building a web application with Vue.js. I am trying to add Auth0 by going through the Auth0 Vue SDK Quickstart. I am able to get the user to log in and display their user information on a profile page. $auth is valid in all of my Vue components.

The issue is I am trying to create an API client with Axios that uses an interceptor to add an Authorization header. When I try to use $auth.getTokenSilently() $auth is always null. I’m doing something very similar to https://forum.vuejs.org/t/using-auth0-spa-with-axios-wrapper/79187/3. I also tried to use this https://community.auth0.com/t/issue-with-auth-being-null/44642 to fix the issue but getInstance() is null.

Here is my main.js

```
Vue.use(Auth0Plugin, {
  domain,
  clientId,
  onRedirectCallback: appState => {
    router.push(
      appState && appState.targetUrl
        ? appState.targetUrl
        : window.location.pathname

const myApp = new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

export default myApp;
```

Repository.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import myApp from "@/App";

const baseDomain = 'http://localhost:8000';
const baseURL = `${baseDomain}/api`;

export const httpClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: baseURL,
  headers: {
    "Context-Type": "application/json"
  }
});

httpClient.interceptors.request.use(async (config) => {
  const token = await myApp.$auth.getTokenSilently(); 
  config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${token}`;
  return config
}, (error) => {
  return Promise.reject(error);
})
```

Then in my store.js I am using a factory pattern to use the httpClient. If you have any ideas please let me know!

EDIT
Looking at the problem more it seems I need to load the Auth0 plugin using a promise to make sure it's loaded before being used.

Comment: Can you add the content of the `Auth0Plugin`?. It seems the solution is to use the `getInstance` method but we need to check how it works inside the Auth0Plugin

Comment: I did it exactly how they have it in their quick start guide https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs#create-an-authentication-wrapper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying a few different solutions this one worked! Make sure to await on the action.

https://community.auth0.com/t/auth0-client-is-null-in-vue-spa-component-on-page-refresh/38147/6?u=simisav

Answer (score 0):

After having a look at [the tutorial](https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/spa/vuejs/01-login), I'd say the simplest way forward is to add the Auth0 `Vue` instance as a global property to `Vue` like this in your plugin

```js
export const Auth0Plugin = {
  install(Vue, options) {
    const auth = useAuth0(options)

    Vue.$auth = auth // global property
    Vue.prototype.$auth = auth // instance property
  }
}
```

You can then access this in your Axios interceptor

```js
import axios from 'axios';
import Vue from "vue";

// snip

const token = await Vue.$auth.getTokenSilently();
```

See also https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/plugins.html#Writing-a-Plugin

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to respond. 
It seems when the Axios interceptor runs $auth isn't set yet. I have been trying different options with no luck. I also put a question on their Auth0 community board. Hopefully, someone answers there.